# Can you get the Windows 11 style menus/buttons etc... in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, windows-11

I am currently developing a small WPF application.

I have noticed that, especially in Windows 11, the `Button` and `Menu` controls look noticeably dated. Win 11 brought rounding to all of these, but WPF seems to be using an older, more square, styling:

*Typical rounded button in a Win11 application vs. the default look of the `<Button/>` control in WPF:*

[image: An example of a rounded Windows 11 style button]
[image: Default WPF button style]

This also applies to the `<Menu />` - if we take a look at a typical program's menu UI styling under Windows 11 vs. the style in my WPF application:

[image: Newer windows 11 menu style]
[image: WPF default Menu control appearance]

Why does WPF have these different styles? I have been reading around and there's lots of mention about adding a reference to `Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls` in `app.manifest` but this doesn't seem to have made any difference to these controls in my case.

What's more confusing is that the actual WPF window itself has rounded corners, and the context menu for right clicking the title bar of this window is using the new style - it seems to be controls *inside* the window that are plagued with the older styles.

Any help/info would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

WPF is officialy dead. That's probably the reason it doesn't receive new features, like the new theme (and more than 60 fps, stereoscopic rendering or native DirectX 12 without a picture buffer to transfer to DirectX 11 in WPF). Those other apps are using the Windows API for GUI, so they don't need to be even recompiled to get the new design. WPF is drawing GUI on its own, so it would need a not-so-small update, which is not economical.